# What word is properly used to mean "rejecting" a phone call?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a standard word that means some one has rejected a phone call? I have been saying it this way:

*She has rejected the call.*

Is there a more appropriate word to use instead of *rejected* in the above sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was the rejection made after caller and recipient communicated directly with each other after initial connection has been completed?

(IMHO)
I can see how this might be "She declined the call" if recipient proactively but politely informed the caller that she did not wish to participate on this occasion.
*"Suzie declined to participate in the survey."*

"She refused the call" if the recipient informed the caller either directly or through a proxy that she would not continue.
*"Suzie told her assistant to refuse the call and charges."*

"She rejected the call" feels like it may involve the recipient not communicating her wishes directly with the caller to cease communication.
*"Suzie programmed her iphone to reject my call."*

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion if one wants to be polite it is better to avoid these two words altogether. Alternatives are:

1. *She is not taking any calls at the moment*.
2. *she did not take my call*.

Replacing *refuse* and *reject* with *not taking calls* makes it more neutral and polite - in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that there is any one word that is required here. A number of different words might suit your purpose, depending on the exact sense of what you mean to say.

*Reject* can be used, although admittedly that may not be the most commonly used word here.

Perhaps the most commonly used word here would be *refused* the call (or *refused to take* the call).

To reiterate, there are options. One example would be this: Perhaps you wish to emphasize that she simply did not want to pay attention to the call at all. In that case, you might say she *ignored* the call.